# merge nested dictionary and list of dictionaries, python

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I would like to combine two nested dictionaries that have a slight structure (one is a list of dictionaries and the other one is a nested dictionary). I would very much appreciate your help!

```
GPP_projects =
[{'CompanyId': 61149,
  'Id': 44},
 {'CompanyId': 61307,
  'Id': 45}]

GPP_companies = 
{61149: {
  'Name': 'xyz',
  'CompanyId': 61149},
 61307: {
  'Name': 'abc',
  'CompanyId': 61307}}

#wanted outcome
GPP_combined =
[{'CompanyId': 61149,
  'Id': 44,
  'Name': 'xyz'}
 {'CompanyId': 61307,
  'Id': 45,
  'Name': 'abc'}}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `pandas` approach or you could simply do the following

```py
GPP_combined = [{**data, **GPP_companies.get(data['CompanyId'], {})} for data  in GPP_projects]
```

This will check if there is `CompanyId` in the `GPP_companies` dict, if so it will add it in. If there are no id in there `GPP_companies` it returns an empty dict which will do nothing.

Depending on what you want to do in the following cases:

- no `CompanyId` in `GPP_companies` ?
- if there are errors in `GPP_companies` which means {**a, **b} will over write valid fields in `GPP_projects`

**output**

```py
GPP_projects =[{'CompanyId': 61149,
  'Id': 44},
 {'CompanyId': 61307,
  'Id': 45,}]

GPP_companies = {61149: {
  'Name': 'xyz',
  'CompanyId': 61149},
 61307: {
  'Name': 'abc',
  'CompanyId': 61307}}

#wanted outcome
GPP_combined =[{'CompanyId': 61149,
  'Id': 44,
  'Name': 'xyz'},
 {'CompanyId': 61307,
  'Id': 45,
  'Name': 'abc'}]

GPP_combined = [
{**data, **GPP_companies.get(data["CompanyId"], {})} 
for data in GPP_projects
]
"""
>> GPP_combined

[{'CompanyId': 61149, 'Id': 44, 'Name': 'xyz'},
 {'CompanyId': 61307, 'Id': 45, 'Name': 'abc'}]
"""
```

for `python 2.7`

```py
for data in GPP_projects:
    company_id = data['CompanyId']
    company_obj = GPP_companies.get(company_id)
    if company_rec:
         data['Name'] = company_obj['Name']
```

This modified `GPP_projects` or you can do a copy to ensure that you are not modifying `GPP_projects`.

Comment: This gave me a TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable; I replaced 'id' with 'CompanyId'

Comment: yeah it was a copy paste issue. You should also have look at creating structured datasets with pandas :)

Comment: I tried GPP_combined = [{**data, **GPP_companies.get(data["CompanyId"], {})} for data in GPP_projects] but it still doesn't work...

Comment: I just confirmed it works - are you using `python 2.7` ?

Comment: You are right, I made some mistakes in providing the datasets! It works now, thanks a lot!